# Get user click event as each image in android gallery is selected

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, android-intent

I'm using this awesome tutorial for xamarin forms in order to get multiple images from gallery on android devices: https://www.xamboy.com/2019/03/12/select-multiple-images-and-videos-in-xamarin-forms/

Everything is working fine. I wonder if there's a way, on code implementation for Android, to intercept when user click on each image.

Right now there is just method for OnActivityResult. Any idea?

Comment: You mean that you need the image to be clickable?

Comment: No. Take a look to edited post

Comment: I **think** you mean can you get the clicks on the images in the **picker**?  If so, that it is not very clear from you post at all.  But the answer is no, that is a system dialog and it does not expose the individual click events.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe use something like that:

```
    <Image>
        <Image.GestureRecognizers>
            <TapGestureRecognizer NumberOfTapsRequired="1" Tapped="MyMethodThatFiresWhenImageIsTapped"/>
        </Image.GestureRecognizers>
    </Image>
```

Comment: I didn’t mean other thing. Take a look at edited post